# STM32F303 USART Configuration

Tags: c, microcontroller, stm32, usart

I am pretty new in ARM and try to configure the UART. The Board I use is a
STM32F3 Discovery. At the moment I only try to get a tx signal on PA9 from USART1, the interrupt routine for rx is not written yet. In my opinion I should see a signal on PA9 when I use an oscilloscope, but the PIN has constant 3V from the pull-up. I used the reference manual for configuration and initialized all the registers as described. Do you see any mistake? My code so far:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * CMSIS-RTOS 'main' function template
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define osObjectsPublic                     // define objects in main module
#include "osObjects.h"                      // RTOS object definitions
#include "stm32f3xx.h"                  // Device header

/*
 * Defines
 */
 #define SYS_FREQUENCY 8000000L //8Mhz

 /*
  * Global Variables
    */

 long baudrate=9600;

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 void initGPIO() {      
        // initialize peripherals here
        //Activate red LED Port
        RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOEEN;              //enable PORTE clock
        GPIOE->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0;            //PORTE9 (LED red) is output
 }

 void initUSART(long baudrate) {
     long baudratio=SYS_FREQUENCY/baudrate;

     //Clock
     RCC->AHBENR |= RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;             //enable PORTA clock
     RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_USART1EN | RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN;       //ENABLE USART1 Clock

     //AF
     GPIOA->AFR[1] = 0;
     GPIOA->AFR[0] = GPIO_AFRL_AFRL7 & (7U<<8);     //AF7 Configuration

     //TX (PA9)
     GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER9_1 ;                                                                      //Alternating function, for TX (PA9)
     GPIOA->OTYPER = 0;                                                                                                             //Push-Pull
     GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9_0 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9_1;     //Fast Speed
     GPIOA->PUPDR |= GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR9_0;                                                                           //Pull-Up

     //RX (PA)
     GPIOA->OSPEEDR |= GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10_0 | GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10_1; //Fast Speed

     //USART
     USART1->CR1 =0;                                                                                                                                        //Reset
     USART1->CR2 =0;                                                                                                                                        //Reset
     USART1->CR3 =0;                                                                                                                                        //Reset
     USART1->BRR = baudratio & 0xFFFF;                                                                                                  //set Baudrate to 9600
     USART1->CR1 |= (USART_CR1_TE |USART_CR1_TXEIE | USART_CR1_RXNEIE| USART_CR1_RE);       //TX, RX Enable, Interrupts Enable
     USART1->CR1 |=  USART_CR1_UE;                                                                                                          //Enable USART
 }

 void sendChar(char c) {
         while(USART_ISR_TXE==1);                           //Data transfered to shift register
         USART1->TDR = (c & 0xFF);
         GPIOE->BSRRL = GPIO_BSRR_BS_9;      //LED on -> BSRRL is Bit Set Reset Register -> write 1 -> high
     osDelay(50);                           
     GPIOE->BSRRH =  GPIO_BSRR_BS_9 ;    //LED off
     osDelay(50);
 }

 void sendXThread(void const *argument) {
     while(1) {
        osDelay(150);
        sendChar('X');
     }
 }

 osThreadDef(sendXThread,osPriorityNormal,1,0);

 //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main (void) {
  osKernelInitialize ();                    // initialize CMSIS-RTOS

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    initGPIO();
    initUSART(baudrate);
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  // create 'thread' functions that start executing,
  // example: tid_name = osThreadCreate (osThread(name), NULL);
    osThreadCreate(osThread (sendXThread),NULL);
  osKernelStart ();                         // start thread execution 
}
```

Comment: I would double check your alternate function configuration. This is a multi-bit field, so you will only get the desired value if all those bits are initially zero. I'd also double check that you are using the correct baud rate calculation, although if that were wrong, you should still see toggling on the line.

Comment: I edited the AF initialization in the code above, but still no success.

Comment: So, we're all on the same page [document], can you post the link to the specific STM32 doc you're using. Also, I agree about _not_ ORing when doing init. Always do direct set [I never trust the "default" values in docs until I prove them]. Try recompile with optimization off. Can you track progress with _multiple_ LEDs? (i.e. can you output an (e.g. 8 bit) code and use it like "printf debugging"). Will the `sendXThread` work directly after `initUSART` (i.e.) skip the OS thread create and start?

Comment: The `stm32f3xx.h` file does a bunch of `#if`/`#elif` to include the _specific_ `.h` for your platform. What is that file (e.g. `stm32f302xc.h`)?

Comment: I use the following Datasheet for the AF: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/2c/6f/d7/64/1f/a3/4f/c9/DM00118585.pdf/files/DM00118585.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00118585.pdf and this one as reference manual: http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/4a/19/6e/18/9d/92/43/32/DM00043574.pdf/files/DM00043574.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00043574.pdf I now changed the ORing but still no success. What do you mean with output an 8bit code? Via GPIO? The sendXThread will work directly after initUSART.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(USART_ISR_TXE==1);
```

`USART_ISR_TXE` is a defined constant (`#define USART_ISR_TXE (1 << 7)`) and it has nothing common with `ISR` register itself. You are just comparing 2^7 with 1.